# Simple scanning String parsing task fails

Tags: java

Does anybody know the string parsing fails in this method, I have no idea. 
I would really like to put this method into action, in my project I am working on.
Thank you and kind regards.

```
public static void loadActiveGameStateSprites(){
    try {    
        // Clears and sets resources 
        activeGameStateSprites.clear();

        try {
            fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("res/allGameStatesSpriteStats.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.out.println("An error has occured during the file Read operation of method loadActiveGameStateManager"); 
        }

        // creates all sprites, sort and reads x, y, image file path, 
        while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
            String readLine = fileScanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("test readLine: " + readLine);                
            String[] lineValues = readLine.split(",");               
            for (String lineValue : lineValues) {
                lineValue.trim();
                System.out.println("test lineValue: " + lineValue);
            }

            int x = Integer.parseInt(lineValues[0]); // <--------- does not work
           // int y = Integer.parseInt(lineValues[1]);  <--------- does not work
           // String spritePath = lineValues[2];        <--------- does not work                 
           // Platformable p = new Platformable(x, y, 80, 80, spritePath); <--------- therefor cannot not work
            //activeGameStateSprites.add(p);

            if (activeLastScannedValue <= activeNextScanValue){          // if (!(activeLastScannedValue > activeNextScanValue)){              
                activeLastScannedValue++;
            } else {
                numScanValuesToBeReadActiveIndex++;
                activeNextScanValue = numScanValuesToBeReadPerGameStates[numScanValuesToBeReadActiveIndex];
            }
        } 

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("An error has occured in method loadGameStateSprites()");
    }
}
```

The txt file looks like this (without the blank lines):

100, 50, images/testImage1.png

20, 30, images/testImage2.png

40, 50, images/testImage3.png

60, 70, images/testImage4.png

80, 10, images/testImage5.png

40, 40, images/testImage6.png

50, 90, images/testImage7.png

300, 500, images/testImage8.png

All values of the first line read are stored correctly 
I have printed them out and tested them.

example:
liveValues[0] = 100;

liveValues[1] = 50;

liveValues[2] = images/testImage1.png;

<---------------------------- at this point the exception e is caught

```
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           System.out.println("An error has occured during the file Read operation of method loadActiveGameStateManager"); 
        }
```

Printing the stacktrace uotputs this:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at GameStateManager.loadActiveGameStateSprites(GameStateManager.java:89)
at GameStateManager.loadActiveGameState(GameStateManager.java:59)
at GameStateManager.<init>(GameStateManager.java:34)
at GamePanel.<clinit>(GamePanel.java:23)
at GameFrame.<clinit>(GameFrame.java:9)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 19 seconds)

Comment: What does `System.out.println("test readLine: " + readLine);` print? (In other words, we need more information about what the output is and what error you're getting

Comment: What exception do you get? What the stacktrace says?

Comment: OK understood I will print whats happening.

Comment: instead of System.out.println("An error.."); try printing the stackTrace using e.printStackTrace() and post the stackTrace

Comment: OK then, of course the stack trace.

Comment: Is there a space after the `,` in the input file? if yes, remove it.

Comment: Yes there is a space after each filed value in the read text file but I have trimmed the values in the enhanced for statement above. They are probably best removed though for simplification.

Comment: @S_BISHOP review your trimming code, it does not change `lineValue` nor does it change `lineValues`

Comment: I would also log (print) the number of line where the exception raises to ease the search of the root of the possible problems. Now we understand that there's a line in your file that doesn't contain the desired number.

Comment: Oh right, Strings are immutable in Java thanks for the reminder, so a new string is return in its place.

Comment: The problem is in your file. Again, as I recommended, you should use an `int counter = 0;` variable that will increase after reading a line and use it when printing/logging the exception to check which line of your file gives you problems. Looks like your file ends with an empty string, which causes this problem.

Comment: I found the solution, I forget that text file characters are so literal. I had a blank line in the text file, meaning the cursor was visibly on the next line, because white space is included as characters. This can be viewed by pressing the backspace key or pressing the space key and then saving the file, It can then be view that the file size in bytes increases/descreases a number of bytes per white space characters, give or take. Thank you everyone for you participation in this query :)

Comment: A simple debugging would have saved lot of people's time

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I wasted hours on this.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simplified version of your code which also checks if a line is blank (even though you mentioned its not blank). My code is working correctly. You can plug in your code here to use all those split tokens for making sprites and such.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Games {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner fileScanner;
        String readLine;
        String[] lineValues;

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        String spritePath = null;

        try {
            fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/temp/a.txt"));
            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                readLine = fileScanner.nextLine();

                if (readLine.length() != 0) {
                    lineValues = readLine.split(",");
                    x = Integer.parseInt(lineValues[0].trim());
                    y = Integer.parseInt(lineValues[1].trim());
                    spritePath = lineValues[2].trim();
                    System.out.println(x + "," + y + "," + spritePath);

                }

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```